# What is kCMTimeIndefinite in iOS ？

Tags: ios, xcode

I print VOD duration : self.avPlayer.currentItem.duration 
output is nan when avPlayer dose not playing 。Why ？

The documents in Xcode ，Before the underlying duration has been loaded, the value of this property is kCMTimeIndefinite. Use key-value observation to
    obtain a valid duration as soon as it becomes available.

But what is kCMTimeIndefinite ？ Why output nan ？

Comment: Obviously because the underlying duration has not been loaded yet. Use key-value observation to obtain a valid duration as soon as it becomes available.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremedia/kcmtimeindefinite?language=objc